# Java GUI fields won't update and will show me white screen

Tags: java

I am making a Java program that captures serial messages from Arduino and makes them visible in GUI. The problem is that I have a loop that constantly receives messages and uses JLabel.setText() method to update JLabel value. The values I get are correct but the GUI part will show me only a white screen with nothing there. I guess there is some problem with the while(true) part because when I remove it I get the static GUI, but I need to change values dynamically.

```
package Arduino;

import javax.sound.sampled.BooleanControl;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Basic {
    public Basic(SerialCommChannel channel) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame basicFrame=new JFrame();
        basicFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel stateLabel=new JLabel("State: ");
        JLabel smartLightLabel=new JLabel("Smart Light System: ");
        //JLabel waterLevelLabel=new JLabel("Water Level");

        basicFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        JLabel stateValue=new JLabel();
        JLabel smartLightValue=new JLabel();
        basicFrame.getContentPane().add(stateLabel);
        basicFrame.getContentPane().add(stateValue);
        basicFrame.getContentPane().add(smartLightLabel);
        basicFrame.getContentPane().add(smartLightValue);
        basicFrame.setSize(300,300);
        basicFrame.setVisible(true);

        while(true){
            String value=channel.receiveMsg();
            String[] infoPack=value.split("@");
            stateValue.setText(infoPack[0]);
            smartLightValue.setText(infoPack[1]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to create the GUI separate from updating the values of the Swing components on the GUI.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: Add a tag to identify your choice of GUI framework.